# Span of similar matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $D=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\\ \end{pmatrix}$

How can i find the span of all matrices A that are similar to D.

thus $\exists P$  $A=P^{-1}DP$

Comment: But the matrices that are similar to a matrix are not a subspace! What do you mean with this ‘span’ ? The orbit under the action of $\operatorname{GL}(2,K)$?

Comment: I think he just means the set of all matrices $A$ such that $A = P^{-1}DP$ for some invertible matrix $P$

Comment: Any subset of these matrices will *span* a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are four matrices similar to $D$ which span all of $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix},
   \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix},
   \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix},
   \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}  $$

So the span of matrices $A$ similar to $D$ is all of (real) $2\times 2$ matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the general definition of an invertible $2\times 2$ matrix for $P$. Then you can invert this matrix and conjugate $D$ with it. The resulting matrix gives you all the matrices $A$.

Note: I don't know if there is a more elegant solution but this definitely works.